# I am working on Jmeter load test. I want to maintain the incremented counter value for the next requests, however, the counter value resets to 0 again

Tags: jmeter, counter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am working on Jmeter load test. I want to maintain the incremented counter value for the next parallel requests [each request defined under throughput controller], however, the counter value resets to 0 again for the subsequent requests.

Here is how my test plan looks like -

+Thread group

+counter (starts from 0 and increments by 1 ; ref name : index)

+Throughput controller [total execution : 1]

- http request1  - uses index with value 0 in the request which is fine.

+Throughput controller [total execution : 2]

- http request2  - should use index with value 1 and 2 , however the counter again resets to 0 and uses value 0 and 1 for 2 executions.

+Throughput controller [ total execution : 3]

- http request3 - should use index with value 3 , 4, 5 ; instead uses value 0,1,2 as counter resets for this as well.

How do i maintain the counter value so that i can run these requests with the desired index values.

Thanks for your help here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct functionality in JMeter Counter to handle your problem.  Either you can use Beanshell sampler OR you can handle your scenario through a workaround with Counter as explained below:

Control the number of Throughput controllers execution via variables.

For example create 3 variables:

```
Controller1_ExecutionTimes: 1
Controller2_ExecutionTimes: 2
Controller3_ExecutionTimes: 3
```

Now you can use these variables to set starting point of your counters.

- Set start point of counter1 as 0
- Set start point of counter2 as ${Controller1_ExecutionTimes}
- Set start point of counter3 as ${Controller1_ExecutionTimes} + ${Controller2_ExecutionTimes}

and so on.

Comment: Hi Arif, Thanks for a quick reply on this one.

Comment: However, the solution suggested does not solve my problem, as somehow counters are not recognizing the values set for user defined variables and not picking their values.

Comment: The behaviour remains the same as before :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arif,

I used the beanshell sampler, extracted the counter value and applied logic to solve my problem.